# Remove rel="noopener noreferrer" from every WordPress blog post within the blog

Tags: html, wordpress

I have a blog with over 50 blog posts and just realised that all the internal links within the posts contain `rel="noopener noreferrer"`. Is there anyway to remove them all in WordPress? Maybe a plugin or a script for the Functions.php?

I researched and can't find any useful content.

Comment: Google it.. First result - [Remove rel = “noopener noreferrer” in wordpress](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/remove-rel-noopener-noreferrer-in-wordpress-4-7-4/#post-9057556)

Comment: Hi Sky, that post is almost 3 years old and I don't see the solution

Answer (score 0):

You can use `preg_replace` to alter the code of the content in WordPress.

```
add_filter('the_content', 'remove_link_rel');
function remove_link_rel($content){
    $content = preg_replace('~<a(.*?)rel="noopener noreferrer"(.*?)>~i', '<a$1$2>', $content);
    return $content;
}
```

Above code checks for the link which contains `rel="noopener noreferrer"` attribute and then removes it. Add this code in your theme's functions.php file.

https://www.phpliveregex.com/p/sey#tab-preg-replace

Comment: Hey Ramesh, I tried this method but its not removed them :)

Comment: Try this one: Replace `preg_replace('~<a(.*?)rel="noopener noreferrer"(.*?)>~i', '<a$1$2>', $content)` with `preg_replace('~<a(.*?)rel="(.*?)"(.*?)>~i', '<a$1$3>', $content)`. Can you share the code of single.php file?

Comment: That didn't work either sorry. The single.php code is <?php * @since 1.0.0
 */

get_header(); ?>

<?php if ( astra_page_layout() == 'left-sidebar' ) : ?>

 <?php get_sidebar(); ?>

<?php endif ?>
 <div id="primary" <?php astra_primary_class(); ?>>
  <?php astra_primary_content_top(); ?>
  <?php astra_content_loop(); ?>
  <?php astra_primary_content_bottom(); ?>
 </div>
<?php if ( astra_page_layout() == 'right-sidebar' ) : ?>
 <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php endif ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>

Comment: I tried the code with the Astra theme and it works there. Take the help from a developer or ask your theme provider for support. Sorry :) One last try, check this file in your theme: `template-parts/single/single-layout.php`. Is `the_content()` function is there? Also, try to deactivate plugins and check if any plugin is overriding `the_content()` function.